# Extension manifest content scripts matches local files

Tags: firefox-addon-webextensions

I would like to know if it is possible to add a content script file to a local extension file named for example "test.html", I tried the following but I can not get it to work :

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["popup/test.html"],
      "all_frames":true,
      "js": ["js/content_script_test.js"]
    }
]
```

I am trying to do this because I would like to be able to use Message Passing from my background script.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a content script for this, APIs like `browser.runtime.sendMessage()` and `browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener()` are available in extension pages, including popups.